# ajax:success not triggering ajax rails 4 app

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, recaptcha

I have jQuery function in rails application from which I am trying to make ajax calls.

The problem is its not returning ajax response but its sending ajax calls successfully.

I need to bind my ajax call with that function so I may be able to show response.

**jQuery code:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#contact_us").bind("ajax:success", function (e, data, status, xhr) {
        if (data.success) {
            $("#alert_success").show();
            $(".CaptchaError").html(data.message);
        } else {
            $("#alert_failed").show();
            $(".CaptchaError").html(data.message);
        }
    });
});
```

**Rails Code:**

```
class MailController < ApplicationController
  prepend_before_action :check_captcha

  def contact_us
    full_name     = params['contact_full_name']
    last_name     = params['contact_last_name']
    phone         = params['contact_phone']
    website       = params['contact_website']
    email         = params['contact_email']
    message       = params['contact_message']
    ContactMailer.send_email(full_name, last_name, phone, website, email, message)
  end

  private
  def check_captcha
    unless verify_recaptcha
      return render json: {:success => false, :message => "You cant use this captcha code"}
    else
      contact_us
      return render json: {:success => true, :message => "Your email has been sent successfully"}
    end
  end
end
```

**Rails Form:**

```
<%=form_tag contact_us_mail_index_path, :id => "contact_us", 
:format => :json, :remote => true do %>

<%end%>
```

**Button Code:**

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-default"><i class="fa
 fa-check"></i> SEND MESSAGE</button>
```

**application.js**

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require plugins/jquery/jquery-2.2.3.min.js
//= require scripts
//= require plugins/slider.revolution/js/jquery.themepunch.tools.min
//= require plugins/slider.revolution/js/jquery.themepunch.revolution.min
//= require view/demo.revolution_slider
//= require plugins/smoothscroll
//= require contact
```

**routes.rb**

```
resources :mail, except: [:show,:new,:create,:edit,:update,:destroy] do
    collection do
      post :contact_us
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After number of attempts I finally resolved the problem.

The problem is related to **turbolinks**. Based on my research the problem was in **application.js** file.

I made number of changes and found **turbolinks** js is creating problem.

So, I installed a gem named: [jquery-turbolinks](https://github.com/kossnocorp/jquery.turbolinks)

After installation, my application.js is like:

```
//= require plugins/jquery/jquery-2.2.3.min
//= require jquery.turbolinks
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require scripts
//= require contact
```

The answer posted my [@SpunkyLive answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38472801/5084534) really helped me a lot but it was not enough to give me direction and fix for the code as well.

Answer (score 0):

I think You should create a file `contact_us.js.erb`

**contact_us.js.erb**

```
if ("<% @success %>") 
  $("#alert_success").show();
else 
  $("#alert_failed").show();

$(".CaptchaError").html("<% @msg %>");
```

**Form**

Remove `format: json`

```
<%=form_tag contact_us_path, :id => "contact_us", :remote => true do %>

<%end%>
```

**HomeConrtoller**

```
def contact_us
  respond_to do |format|
    if verify_recaptcha
      full_name     = params['contact_full_name']
      last_name     = params['contact_last_name']
      phone         = params['contact_phone']
      website       = params['contact_website']
      email         = params['contact_email']
      message       = params['contact_message']
      ContactMailer.send_email(full_name, last_name, phone, website, email, message)
      @success = true
      @msg = "Your email has been sent successfully"
      format.js 
    else
      @success = false
      @msg = "You cant use this captcha code"
      format.js
    end
  end
end
```

**Routes**

```
post '/contact_us' => 'home#contact_us', as: :contact_us
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: I tried your code and it says: `Template is missing 
Missing template mail/contact_us, application/contact_us with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:js, :html
], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :coffee, :jbuilder]}. Searched in:`

Comment: One More thing Paste you routes also. I think `contact_us_mail_index_path` is a `GET`

Comment: added the routes as well. please review.

Comment: Did you reviewed my routes for `contact_us_mail_index_path`?

Comment: Yes, You can work with that but replace `except: [:show,:new,:create,:edit,:update,:destroy]` to `only: [] ` And add replace the form path according to your route

Comment: and also need to change routes as you said? It also necessary?

Comment: tried you code it says: `Template is missing

Missing template mail/contact_us, application/contact_us with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:js, :html
], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :coffee, :jbuilder]}. Searched in:`

Comment: Where you created the `contact_us.js.erb` file

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117776/discussion-between-spunkylive-and-learningror).